# How to pin a specific batch file to start menu or task bar

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, taskbar, start-menu

I have a batch file that I want to run easily on Windows 10.

I am trying to pin it either to the start menu, or the task bar, or at least have it come up when I search from the start menu.

I have created a shortcut to the batch file, but when I right click on it (or the batch file) there is no options to pin to task or start menu.

Is there a way I can do this in Windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

Just try to create a folder (and subfolder, if necessary, for ps1, sh, cmd, bat, etc.). In this folder, you can place all your script files or shortcuts to them (as I did) and add this folder to the taskbar as you can see in the gif below:

This is my folder named `☺☻`:

For name: **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>**, **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>**

Folder for sample taskbar layout:

```
%HomeProfile%\☺☻\
                |-------\Pin_Bash\
                |                 |-------: Your_Script_#1.sh
                |                 |-------: Your_Script_#2.sh
                |                 |-------: Your_Script_#3.sh
                |
                |-------\Pin_PS1\
                |                |-------: Your_Script_#1.ps1
                |                |-------: Your_Script_#2.ps1
                |                |-------: Your_Script_#3.ps1
                |
                |-------\Pin_Cmd\
                                 |-------: Your_Script_#1.cmd
                                 |-------: Your_Script_#2.bat
                                 |-------: Your_Script_#3.bat
```

You can create a second menu, or submenu, for your Script, Players, Browsers, DevSofters, Games, etc ..., adding new folders in the root menu / `Task_Bar / Folder` and easily navigate them as a custom menu:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pin scripts to the taskbar, but you can pin shortcuts to the taskbar if you alter them. So create a shortcut to the script somewhere. Access its properties, and change the shortcut to the following by prepending `cmd.exe /c` :

```
cmd.exe /c "C:\temp\myscript.cmd"
```

... where it refers to your script.

then right-click the shortcut, and given it points to an executable, you can now pin that to the task bar. Do note that it will always spawn a new window, so for as long as the script runs, you will have 2 taskbar entries.

Scripts should show up in the start menu on searches though, if its location is indexed.

Comment: You didn't read the whole question.

Comment: @ScottF My apologies. I forgot a crucial part. I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: this works. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the shortcut is on the desktop, then it will be available in the Start menu.

You could also copy the shortcut manually into the Start menu folder at
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`.